# Difference between Gradle home directory and Gradle offline directory

Tags: android, gradle

In Android Studio settings there are two paths for gradle. The first is in project-level_setting called `Gradle home:`, and second is Global_level_setting `service directory path:`, which I use for offline gradle path.

What is the difference and what exactly is this path for? I googled and could not find a clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Service Directory Path is the default Gradle Home directory. This is where the cache is maintained.

Basically it overrides the default Gradle:Home when entering in offline mode , Gradle will look for dependencies there (in the cache) because it does not have acces to the network ; which is kind of a heatburn if you do that.

**NOTE : Gradle home - it is speciffied the fully qualified path to your Gradle installation.**